# What IoC Containers Support Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, inversion-of-control

I'm looking for a list of IoC Containers that support Silverlight. I know that **Unity** and **Ninject** work with Silverlight, but I haven't found any information that suggests that other well known containers, like **StructureMap**, **Castle Windsor** or Autofac, support Silverlight.

Has anyone used these, or other, containers or compared them with the Silverlight platform in mind?

Comment: There's a plan to port Castle Windsor to Silverlight. However none of the core committers is working in Silverlight so we're looking for people who would like to testdrive it, and report issues back. If you're interested drop us a line on Castle Users group: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of Silverlight supported IoC containers:
- Ayende's "[Building an IoC container in 15 seconds](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/20/Building-an-IoC-container-in-15-lines-of-code.aspx)"
- Castle Windsor - You can grab the binary from the [RhinoMocks for Silverlight download](http://www.ayende.com/20/section.aspx/download/230).
- [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list)
- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/download)
- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18855)

StructureMap and Spring.Net currently do not support Silverlight with shipping binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.1.1, Castle Windsor does.